# How will study as a non-degree student affect my graduate admissions chances later?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

I am considering applying to a computer science department at an esteemed US university, university A, as a non-degree seeking student. The reason is three-fold:

- Determine if what I'm studying is truly what I want to do.
- Do well in the classes to improve my chances of being accepted to their MS program in the near future.
- Make connections with profs who might be a good academic/research advisor.

My goal is to eventually apply to a PhD program at university B.

Will the non-degree option help my chances at being accepted to university A's MS program?

Will the non-degree option hurt my chances at being accepted to university B's PhD program? Will they need to know about the non-degree if I'm eventually accepted to the degree option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Will the non-degree option help my chances at being accepted to university A's MS program?*

No.

*Will the non-degree option hurt my chances at being accepted to university B's PhD program?*

No.

*Will they need to know about the non-degree if I'm eventually accepted to the degree option?*

Do well in the course and then you'll be proud to share the transcript with them.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I am not sure this is true. Why do you think it won't help him?

Comment: Hmm.  To tell you the truth, I don't remember why I answered no to the first question.  Thanks for the comment -- I can see your point.